# $C^\infty$ version of Urysohn Lemma in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to solve an exercise which its conclusion seems to be the title of this post. The exercise is:

> 1. Show that the function $h:\Bbb R\to [0,1[$ given by
>      $$h(t)=\begin{cases}
>    e^{-1/t^2} &\text{if } t\neq 0\\
>    0          &\text{otherwise}
>    \end{cases}$$
>      is $C^\infty$.
> 2. Show that the functions
>      $$h_+(t)=\begin{cases}
>    e^{-1/t^2} &\text{if } t\gt 0\\
>    0          &\text{otherwise}
>    \end{cases}\quad\text{and}\quad
>    h_{-}(t)=\begin{cases}
>    e^{-1/t^2} &\text{if } t\lt 0\\
>    0          &\text{otherwise}
>    \end{cases}$$
>      are $C^\infty$.
> 3. Show that the function $k:\Bbb R\to [0,1[$ given by $k(t)=h_-(t-b)h_+(t-a)$ is $C^\infty$ and positive for $t\in ]a,b[$.
> 4. Let $R$ the rentangle $]a_1,b_1[\times\cdots\times]a_n,b_n[$. Show that there is a $C^\infty$ function $g:\Bbb R^n\to [0,1[$ strictly positive on $R$.
> 5. Conclude that if $K$ is a compact subset of $\Bbb R^n$ and $U$ is an open neighborhood of $K$, there is a $C^\infty$ function $f:\Bbb R^n\to [0,1]$ such that $f_{|K}\equiv 1$ and its support is contained in $U$.

From 1.-4. I can prove that for any open and bounded set $O\subset \Bbb R^n$, there is a $C^\infty$ function with its support contained in $O$. So my first attempt was apply this to the open $U\setminus K$. Then I get a $C^\infty$ function $f$ that is $0$ (in particular) over $K$. If I just consider $\chi_K+f$ that function can fail to be $C^\infty$.

In a discussion on the chat, robjohn suggest [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6200007#6200007). It works fine, but then my question is:

> Can 5. be proved by using 1.-4.? If yes, how?

Comment: Where are you reaching a snag? That would be helpful in informing people as to where to begin advising.

Comment: Note that 2. implies 1 by adding $h=h_++h_-$. Also 3. follows immediately from 2. and the chain rule. So all you have to show is 2.

Comment: I'd just like to note that this is not the full strength of the smooth Urysohn lemma, since we are assuming $K$ to be compact, and not just closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $K$ is compact and $U^C$ is closed, there is a positive distance, $\Delta$, from $K$ to $U^C$.

We can cover each point $k\in K$ with an open cube $Q_k(\Delta/\sqrt{n})$ centered at $k$ and side $\Delta/\sqrt{n}$. Note that the entire cube is within $\frac\Delta2$ of $k$. Since $K$ is compact, choose a finite subcover of these cubes $\{Q_{k_j}(\Delta/\sqrt{n}):1\le j\le N\}$. For each cube in this subcover, define the function $f_j$ mentioned in step 4 above on $Q_{k_j}(2\Delta/\sqrt{n})$ but divide it by its minimum on $\overline{Q}_{k_j}(\Delta/\sqrt{n})$. Thus, $f_j$ is supported in $Q_{k_j}(2\Delta/\sqrt{n})$ and is $\ge1$ on $Q_{k_j}(\Delta/\sqrt{n})$.

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^Nf_j$ is supported in $U$ and is $\ge1$ on $K$. Then $\phi\circ\sum\limits_{j=1}^Nf_j$ is supported in $U$ and is $1$ on $K$, where

$$\phi(x)=\frac{h_+(x)}{h_+(x)+h_+(1-x)}$$

Note that $\phi\in C^\infty$, and $\phi(x)=0$ for $x\le0$ and $\phi(x)=1$ for $x\ge1$.

Comment: I just found what I've asked is just the Section 2.6 "Constructions of Smooth Functions" of the book _Differentiable Manifolds_ by Lawrence Conlon. What do you mean by "Note that the entire cube is within $\frac{\Delta}{2}.$"

Comment: @leo: If the side of the cube centered at $k$ is $\Delta/\sqrt{n}$, then the distance from $k$ to the corner of the cube is $\Delta/2$.

Comment: @leo: you want the overlap! The important part is that $\sum f_j=0$ outside of $U$ and $\sum f_j\ge1$ on $K$. That way, when you apply $\phi$ it becomes $0$ outside $U$ and $1$ on $K$.

Comment: Ok, I see now. thanks

Comment: It's long time ago, but... Seems like your prove is incomplete. It's possible $x \in U \setminus  K: F(x)=1$ ($F$ is your result function).

Am i wrong? It would be much better to have something like "$=1$ if and only if $x \in K$".

Comment: @Ximik: Urysohn only guarantees that $F(x)=1$ on $K$ and $F(x)=0$ on $U^C$. It is not guaranteed that $0\lt F(x)\lt1$ for $x\in U\setminus K$. Doing something that is $1$ if and only if $x\in K$ might require some condition on the boundary of $K$.

Comment: @robjohn ye, i see. What i want to achieve is $F(x) = 1$ on $K$ and $supp(F) = U$ for some $U$ (i want it only be close enough to $K$). It is just a requirement, based on analogy with 1-4. However i'm not even sure it's possible for ANY $K$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm d}\newcommand{\supp}{\operatorname{supp}}$
This is just the end of the Section 2.6: Constructions of Smooth Functions, in *Differentiable Manifolds* by Lawrence Conlon.

Let $a\lt b$, and consider the function $k:\Bbb R\to [0,1[$ as in 3. Now, let $l:\Bbb R\to[0,1[$ defined by
$$l(x)=\frac{\int_a^x k(t)\d t}{\int_a^b k(t)\d t}.$$
Notice that $l$ is no decreasing, $l\equiv 0$ in $]-\infty,a]$, $l\equiv 1$ in $[b,\infty[$, and $0\lt l(x)\lt 1$ for $x\in ]a,b[$.

Now, as in @robjohn's answer, it's possible to cover $K$ by a  finite number of open intervals, say $\{I_j\}_1^N$, so that $\bar{I_j}\subset U$ for each $j\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$.

For each $j\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$, pick a soft function $g_j:\Bbb R^n\to [0,1[$ as in 4. Then the function $g:\Bbb R^n\to [0,1[$ given by
$$g=g_1+\cdots+g_N$$
is $C^\infty$, positive over $K$ and with
$$\supp(g)\subseteq U.$$
Now, $g$ attains its minimum over $K$, say in $x_\ast\in K$, thus $g(x_\ast)\gt 0$. Let $\delta=g(x_\ast)$.

Take an $l$ as the one discussed at the beginning with $a=0$ and $b=\delta$. The function $f=l\circ g$ have the desired properties.