# Is it possible to extend Urysohn's lemma to $C^1(X)$?

Tags: general-topology

So what I mean precisely: take $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_{eucl})$ can we find a function $f$ for every closed $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $A \subset f^{-1}(\{0\})$ and $B \subset f^{-1}(\{1\})$ and $f'$ is continious?

I think this makes sense because we can find a continious function $f$ such that this is true, and then redefine $f$ in a small neighboorhood around a point where $f'$ is not continious such that it is smooth, but I can't proof it, and I can't find mentoin anywhere on the internet, so I'm wondering whether this is actually true.

Comment: For general topological spaces derivatives make no sense.

Comment: And if $X$ is a differential manifold then a standard partition of unity type of argument should give the result.

Comment: @MoisheCohen you're right, I should have said $\mathbb{R}$, I edited the question.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198748/c-infty-version-of-urysohn-lemma-in-bbb-rn (I got there with the very first result of googling "smooth urysohn")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the smooth situation oe can be much more precise than Unrysohn's lemma: see the [Whitney extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem).