# How to choose smooth function $f:\mathbb R \to [0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, examples-counterexamples

Let $\alpha, \beta >0.$

> Can we  expect to choose differentiable  $f:\mathbb R \to [0,1]$ such that 
>   $f(x+\alpha)=0$ if $x\leq 0,$ and  $f(x-\alpha)=1$ if $x\geq \beta$?  If so, can we  make $f$ smooth?

Comment: I think this is a "bump function" and I've seen them somewhere.

Comment: You have to impose $\alpha < \beta - \alpha$ as otherwise the $f(x) = 0$ and $f(x)=1$ regions overlap.

Comment: @Winther:  Thanks. Can you explain a bit more? Even after assuming this, what one  can expect?

Comment: Also why do they overlap? Thanks..

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198748/c-infty-version-of-urysohn-lemma-in-bbb-rn

Comment: For example $f(\alpha) = 0$ by your first definition and $f(\beta-\alpha) = 1$ by your second definition. If for example $\alpha = \beta - \alpha$ then you have two values for $f$ here.

Comment: @Winther: Thanks. I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With  $u<v:$ Let $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq u.$ Let $f(x)=1$ for $x\geq v.$

Let $ n\in \Bbb Z^+.$

Let $g(y)=(y-u)^{n+1} (y-v)^{n+1}.$ Let $K=\int_u^v g(y)dy.$

For $u<x<v$  let $f(x)=\frac {1}{K}\int_u^x g(y)dy.$

The $n$th derivative of $f$ exists and is continuous at all points.

Note: $K\ne 0$ because either (i) $g(y)>0$ for all $y\in (u,v)$ or (ii) $g(y)<0$ for all $y\in (u,v).$

Comment: Thanks. I like your trick.  Please can  you explain bit more what goes wrong if we want $f$ is smooth (that is $f$ is infinitely many times differentiable)?

Comment: In my answer, replace $g(y)$ with $e^{ h(y) }$ where $h(y)=   \frac {-1} {(y-u)^2(y-v)^2}$ to make $f$ infinitely smooth.... For infinite smoothness neither $f$ nor $g$ can be a polynomial, because  if $f(x)=Ax^m+Bx^{m-1}+...$ is a non-constant  polynomial of degree $m>0 $ when $r x\in (u,v),$  then the $m$th derivative  $f^{(m)}(x)$ is the non-zero constant $m!A$ when $x\in (u,v)$.... but $f^{(m)}(x)=0$ when $x<u.$